# Как открыть webbrowser в окне desktop приложения python

Tags: python

Есть desktop приложение на python написано при помощи tkinter. В конце логики должен открываться browser(по умолчанию). Библиотека webbroser встроенная в Python открывает этот browser в отдельном окне. Вопрос.
Как открыть browser именно в окне приложения?

Comment: Ищите по слову *embedded*.

Comment: все ровно не понял как

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Embedding_Mozilla

Comment: Теперь понятно. Спасибо